# filter for selected record

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-6

I selected a product and then I have this product in a table, when I want to select other product I have to filter the suggestion of the products it should show the options without the product to add to the table. But I dont know how, if you know an option or an idea I'd appreciate it.

query:

```
$Input = $request->key;
                    $almacenOrigen = $request->almacenOrigen;
                    $lengthSku = 16;
                    $Sku = substr($Input, 0, $lengthSku);
                
                    $name = DB::table('products')
                    ->leftJoin('line_products', 'products.lineProduct_id', '=', 'line_products.id')
                    ->leftJoin('inventories', 'products.id', '=', 'inventories.product_id')
                    ->leftJoin('warehouses', 'inventories.warehouse_id', '=', 'warehouses.id')
                    ->where('inventories.status_id', 1)
                    ->where('products.sku', $Sku)
                    ->where('warehouses.id', $almacenOrigen)
                    ->whereNull('products.deleted_at')
                    ->select(
                        'products.sku',
                        'products.reference',
                        'products.id',
                        'products.name as nameP',
                        'line_products.skuLength',
                        'line_products.expirationLength',
                        'line_products.lotLength',
                        'line_products.traceabilityLength',
                        'line_products.name as nameL',
                        'inventories.lot',
                        'inventories.warehouse_id',
                        'inventories.id as inventory_id',
                        'inventories.traceability'
                    )
                    ->get();
                    $html = '';
                    if (!empty($name)) {
                        $Expiration = substr($Input, $name[0]->skuLength, $name[0]->expirationLength);
                        $yearToday = substr(Carbon::now(), 0, 2);
                        $year = $yearToday . substr($Expiration, 2, 2);
                        $month = substr($Expiration, 4, 2);
                        $day = substr($Expiration, 6, 2);
                        $Expiration = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day;
                        $Lot = substr($Input, $name[0]->skuLength + $name[0]->expirationLength, $name[0]->lotLength);
                        $Lot = substr($Lot, 2);
                        $Traceability = substr($Input, $name[0]->skuLength + $name[0]->expirationLength + $name[0]->lotLength, $name[0]->traceabilityLength);
                        $Traceability = substr($Traceability, 2);

                        foreach ($name as $value) {
                            $html .= '
                                <div>
                                    <a style="color: #000000" class="suggest-element" exist="1" inventory_id="'.($value->inventory_id).'" lot="'.($value->lot).'" warehouse_id="'.($value->warehouse_id).'" "' 
                                    . '" sku="' . ($value->sku) 
                                    . '" reference="' . ($value->reference) 
                                    . '" caducidad="' . ($Expiration) 
                                    . '" lote="' . ($Lot) 
                                    . '" trazabilidad="' . ($Traceability) 
                                    . '" nameL="' . ($value->nameL) 
                                    . '" nameP="' . ($value->nameP) 
                                    . '" data="' . ($value->sku . $Expiration . $Lot . $Traceability) 
                                    . '" id="' . $value->id . '">' 
                                    . ($value->inventory_id . "-" .$value->sku .$Expiration . $Lot . $Traceability ) . 
                                    '</a>
                                </div>'
                            ;
```

Example:
This are the suggestions, if I select id = 1 this is added in a table then when I want to select another the id=1 have not to appear.

```
|id |----  sku  ----|
| 1 |108888893024899|
| 2 |108888893024896|
| 3 |108888893024895|
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Selected product"? how exactly do you select it? What happens during selection?

Comment: I added an image, if you see I selected a product id 17 and then It is in the table, later if I want to select another the product with Id 17 is continuous appearing.

Comment: I meant what happens in your code, not in front. Does it call a method to refresh the table? Does selection happen only on user-side, or you are calling server to do something?